# Join of paths in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

if $\gamma_1 : [a_1, a_2] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
and $\gamma_2 : [b_1, b_2] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
then $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 : [a_1, b_1 + b_2 - a_2] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

I have problem understanding diagrammatically why it's $a_2 + b_2 - b_1$.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not $a_2+b_2-b_1$?

Comment: @AlonAmit Oh you are right. and sorry i forgot to add that $\gamma_1 (a_2) = \gamma_2 (b_1)$

Comment: So now that you have it right, do you see why this is true? Place the second interval right after the first and see where it ends.

Comment: @AlonAmit What i am confused with is that can $b_1 < a_2$ ?

Comment: You "slide" the intervall $[b_1,b_2]$ such that $b_1 = a_2$ in its new position